# Socket.IO's once function not working correctly

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

My purpose is to make a chat application using Node.js + Socket.IO, but I met with a difficulty.
The issue is that the `minus` event doesn't work correctly(Result: 64 - 12 = 65), but the `plus` event works fine(Result: 42 + 23 = 65).
Maybe the cause of the issue is related to `socket.once()` function... but I don't know the answer clearly.

The following is the source code of my simplified Node.js app.

**app.js:**

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var socketio = require('socket.io');

var app = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    if (req.url === '/') {
        fs.readFile(__dirname + '/index.html', function (err, result) {
            if (err)
                throw err;

            res.writeHead(200, {
                'Content-Type': 'text/html'
            });
            res.end(result);
        });
    } else {
        res.writeHead(404);
        res.end();
    }
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('The server running on port 3000.');
});

var io = socketio(app);
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('plus', function (param) {
        socket.emit('result', param.a + param.b);
    });

    socket.on('minus', function (param) {
        socket.emit('result', param.a - param.b);
    });
});
```

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title></title>
        <script src="http://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.0.6.js"></script>
        <script>
            var socket = io();

            socket.emit('plus', {
                a: 42,
                b: 23
            });

            socket.once('result', function (result) {
                var div = document.createElement('div');
                div.innerText = '42 + 23 = ' + result;
                document.body.appendChild(div);
            });

            socket.emit('minus', {
                a: 64,
                b: 12
            });

            socket.once('result', function (result) {
                var div = document.createElement('div');
                div.innerText = '64 - 12 = ' + result;
                document.body.appendChild(div);
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Result:**

```
42 + 23 = 65
64 - 12 = 65
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because you bind two event callback on 'result' same time.

```
<script>
    var socket = io();

    socket.emit('plus', {
        a: 42,
        b: 23
    });

    socket.once('result', function (result,obj) {
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.innerText = '42 + 23 = ' + result;
        document.body.appendChild(div);

        socket.emit('minus', {
            a: 64,
            b: 12
        });
        socket.once('result', function (result,obj) {
            var div = document.createElement('div');
            div.innerText = '64 - 12 = ' + result;
            document.body.appendChild(div);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't overload the "once" result like that - they're both being bound right away rather than synchronously.  The correct way to do it would be to use two separate events for the different types of results.

Here's a modified app.js

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var socketio = require('socket.io');

var app = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    if (req.url === '/') {
        fs.readFile(__dirname + '/index.html', function (err, result) {
            if (err)
                throw err;

            res.writeHead(200, {
                'Content-Type': 'text/html'
            });
            res.end(result);
        });
    } else {
        res.writeHead(404);
        res.end();
    }
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('The server running on port 3000.');
});

var io = socketio(app);
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('plus', function (param) {
        socket.emit('plus result', param.a + param.b);
    });

    socket.on('minus', function (param) {
        socket.emit('minus result', param.a - param.b);
    });
});
```

And the corresponding index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title></title>
        <script src="http://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.0.6.js"></script>
        <script>
            var socket = io();

            socket.on('plus result', function (result) {
                var div = document.createElement('div');
                div.innerText = '42 + 23 = ' + result;
                document.body.appendChild(div);
            });

            socket.once('minus result', function (result) {
                var div = document.createElement('div');
                div.innerText = '64 - 12 = ' + result;
                document.body.appendChild(div);
            });

            socket.emit('plus', {
                a: 42,
                b: 23
            });

            socket.emit('minus', {
                a: 64,
                b: 12
            });

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Or send the triggered operation along with the result, as in: `socket.emit("result",{operation:"plus",value:result_of_operation});`

Comment: Realistically - probably shouldn't use once either, as it's not going to be useful for a chat application long term...  but potato / potAto.  :)